# NEAT AI slows down really quickly

Tags: python, pygame, artificial-intelligence

I have created a 2D top-down car sim with Pygame and used NEAT to evolve the car's AI to drive. Each car has 5 raycasts (left, slightly left, forward, slightly right and right) which provide the distance to a wall as the input. There are 4 outputs: accelerate, decelerate, turn right and turn left. Everything works well but even with a low population of 10, but after just a couple of generations the program slows down so much and eventurally crashes. How can I speed this up because I know it's not hardware as I have run this on a powerfull desktop PC and it was the same. It's also not a NEAT limitation as I have seen people make far more complicated projects that work perfectly fine at a stable frame rate.

This is the main eval function. I can show the rest of the code if needed but my guess is that this is where the lag comes from.

```
def remove(id):
nets.pop(id)
ge.pop(id)
cars.pop(id)

def eval_genomes(genomes, config):
setup((700, 700))
setup('fullscreen')

    track.createTrack()
    global nets, ge, cars
    
    nets = []
    ge = []
    
    cars = []
    
    for id, g in genomes:
        g.fitness = 0
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
        nets.append(net)
    
        pos = size(9, 90, screenSize)
        cars.append(Car(screen, pos[0], pos[1], track))
    
        ge.append(g)
    
    
    
    
    for car in cars:
        car.rays = [Ray(car, 0), Ray(car, 45), Ray(car, -45), Ray(car, 90), Ray(car, -90)]
    
    
    frame = 0
    run = True
    while run and frame < 420:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                break
    
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    run = False
                    break
    
        screen.fill((20, 20, 20))
    
    
        track.display()   #display the map
        # track.drawReference()
    
        for id, car in enumerate(cars):
            car.update(cars, ge)           # all vehicle updates like vel, pos, rotation
            car.display()            # renders vehicle. has no effect on the code it just renders.
            ge[id].fitness += 0.1
            output = nets[id].activate(car.data)
    
            if output[0] > 0.75:                                 #inputs
                car.inputs[0] = True
            else:
                car.inputs[0] = False
    
            if output[1] > 0.75:
                car.inputs[1] = True
            else:
                car.inputs[1] = False
    
            if output[2] > 0.75:
                car.inputs[2] = True
            else:
                car.inputs[2] = False
    
            if output[3] > 0.75:
                car.inputs[3] = True
            else:
                car.inputs[3] = False
    
            for line in track.racetrack:
                if car.colliding(line):       #checks collisions
                    remove(id)                #removes that car from all lists so it doesn't matter anymore
                    break
    
        if 0 == len(cars):                    #if all cars are dead it will automatically start the nex gen
            run = False
    
        pygame.display.flip()
        frame += 1
        clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it. It was a me issue and it was that each gen I would create the track which kept piling on the map on top of itself and led it to double the collision checks each generation.